# Usage of "former" in objectives other than human

Tags: adjectives

In a context of talking about the New National Stadium in Tokyo, how you describe the old stadium, which has already be demolished to construct the new one?

I at first thought *"the former national stadium"*, however, it sounded somewhat strange to me as "former" is used to describe person(s) or occupation (e.g. former prime minister), not to other things like buildings, facilities, etc.

If "former" is not appropriate, should I say *"old national stadium"*? But still it sounds weird as "old" might imply the building (stadium) may still be there(not demolished). Please advise, and provide simple and clear expression.

Comment: I see no problem in using "former" for this.

Comment: Questions on ELU are far better (and far less likely to be closed) when accompanied by reasonable research (eg some results obtained by googling "former national stadium", "former church", "former bank"). We recommend that new contributors take the site tour.

Answer (score 2):

[Former](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/former) is correct:

> - Relating to or taking place in the past: *in former times*. (AHD)

Usage example

From [Hong Kong Architecture](https://books.google.it/books?id=c6SxbRTcIC8C&q=%22former%20stadium%22&dq=%22former%20stadium%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqz930ievOAhUGuxQKHf4lBBUQ6AEIKzAC):

> - The challenge became one of providing an entirely modern stadium capable of hosting international sporting and entertainment events for 40,000 patrons while using no more of ***the site than the former stadium***, which accommodated about..